# Python wordlist creation

Tags: python, word-list

So far I am creating a world based game the only thing I need help with is creating a wordlist without having to type each word or re formate hundreds into the correct formatting. Any tips?

so far I have this:

```
fiveLetterWords = ["abuse", "adult", "drama", "drain", "enemy", "entry", "catch", "could", "would", "track", "train", "plain", "plane"]
sixLetterWords = ["people", "things", "really", "abroad", "accept", "belief", "scraps", "trashy", "camera", "create"]
```

I would like to have a few more words than this and if there's a site that has this listed in this format comment it thanks!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cfreshman/a03ef2cba789d8cf00c08f767e0fad7b and guess list https://gist.github.com/cfreshman/a03ef2cba789d8cf00c08f767e0fad7b from wordle

Comment: @AndrewRyan how would i format that to make it side by side and in quotes with commas after each word or would I need to at all?

Comment: @AndrewRyan i need help to add the list into my program and then have the program choose a word from that list and do the thing wordle does with wrong or right characters I have something similar to that right now but its very buggy and doesn't work well at all

Comment: @AndrewRyan can you help me import a wordlist into my program or tell me how

Answer (score 0):

Search for the [most frequent English words](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/english-word-frequency) in Kaggle datasets. then you can grab those which contain 5, 6, or ... letters. also, you can use [this dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zxwK1Y84xPWaJMQAd8yPs7FmCPBdQBoV/view?usp=sharing) that contains the most frequent 5 letters **meaningful** English words that is a combination of two datasets and without any repetition.

simply use this line of code to read the .csv file:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("frequent_5_char_words.csv" , sep=" " , header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Unix like OS, you can use the [words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)) list:

```
words={}
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f: # /usr/dict/words on some
    for word in (w.rstrip() for w in f):
        words.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word)
```

If you only want words of a certain length, you can filter them:

```
words={}
with open('//usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    for word in (w for w in (w.rstrip() for w in f) if 4<=len(w)<=6):
        words.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word)
```

Comment: is there such a dataset in windows 10 too?

Comment: Not natively (I think) but open source and easily installed. [Here](https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/49) is one package. I am sure there are more.

Comment: yeah, I meant natively.

Answer (score 0):

These files are from the wordle game therefore only have 5 letter words.

Download the files from [allowed guess list](https://gist.github.com/cfreshman/cdcdf777450c5b5301e439061d29694c) and
[allowed answer list](https://gist.github.com/cfreshman/a03ef2cba789d8cf00c08f767e0fad7b) (by clicking download zip)
then unzipping them and putting them into the same directory as your script. You can run this to read in those words and use them as part of your wordle game.

```
def read_from_txt_file(filename):
    with open('wordle-allowed-guesses.txt', 'r') as file:
        file_list = [item[:-1] for item in file] # using [:-1] to get rid of the newline character
    return file_list

guess_list = read_from_txt_file('wordle-allowed-guesses.txt')
answer_list = read_from_txt_file('wordle-answers-alphabetical.txt')
```